# Multiple M:N relationships in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have several objects in a database that will all link to one additional type as a collection. My `User` class will have an `ICollection<Download> Downloads`, as will my `Group` class. Because I'm sharing the foreign class I know I'll have to use junction tables (`User_Download` and `Group_Download`). A given `Download` will be associated with exactly one other row--only one object, not multiple split among the two tables. A `User` or `Group` can have any number of `Download`s. `User` and `Group` themselves are not related in any way.

How would I go about mapping this in EF 6 using Fluent API?

A 1:M relationship [requires](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) a key on the many side, and M:N [requires](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) `ICollection`s on either side as well.

*Bonus question: With whatever the answer ends up being, how would I properly delete a `Download` so that it no longer exists and the other object is no longer associated with it?*

Comment: Out of interest; Does `Group` contain a collection of `User`s?

Comment: Perhaps a bad choice of example classes, but `Group` and `User` are not related in any way.